# Who were those "many" in whom the Eldar saw Lúthien's likeness?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

A passage in *The Silmarillion* tells about Lúthien:

> Yet in her choice the Two Kindreds have been joined; and she is the forerunner of many in whom the Eldar see yet, thought all the world is changed, the likeness of Lúthien the beloved, whom they have lost.

*Of Beren and Lúthien, p221*

Who are those "many"? Does it refer to some of the Elven maids who bore the resemblance to Lúthien (most notably, Arwen), does it include males also? Or is it about something else entirely?

Thanks.

Comment: I personally always interpreted this as meaning that all the legendary beauties of human history bore Luthien's likeness.

Answer (score 5):

From Lúthien and Beren's union came Dior.

Dior and Nimloth had three children.  The twins Elured and Elurin were left to starve in the woods following the murder of their parents by Celegorm. Only Elwing escaped and survived.

Elwing had two children: Elrond and Elros.

The likeness of Lúthien would therefore be seen in the family tree from Dior down, splitting at Elrond and Elros into both Elven and Edain lines.

Any exceedling fair member of either line could be expected to be a bearer of Lúthien's likeness.

Dior Eluchíl (*the fair*) is likely to have had some resemblance to his mother, so he is probably the first of The Many.

Arwen would also be a likely bearer of Lúthien's likeness. One would expect her son to have it too (possibly in great quantities) as he would be descended from both the Elrond and Elros branches.

This rather charming family tree from [The Council of Elrond](http://www.thecouncilofelrond.com) shows the lineage nicely.

[image: beren luthien family tree]